# How to design a PI/PID controller with a given bandwidth and phase margin?

Tags: control-system, pid-controller, homework, bandwidth, controller

I've read the article, [Introduction: PID Controller Design](https://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?example=Introduction&section=ControlPID), which explained really well the effect each branch of the controller has on the rise time, settling time, overshoot, and error, which gives some solid intuition for how I might want to adjust the gains of each one one based on the step response plots.

But I have a HW problem where I'm supposed to tune a PI or PID controller for the same mass-spring-damper system used as the example in the linked article (except with particular values of the DE coefficients given) but where the bandwidth is 7.5 rad/s and the PM is 50° and I don't quite understand how to relate those quantities to the transfer function of the system itself or the controller.  Specifically, it's question 5 below (I completed parts 1-4 already):

[image]

In the solution my professor provided, he divided the bandwidth value by 1.5 and said the resulting 5 rad/s was the crossover frequency, but he didn't explain where the 1.5 comes from and it's not clear why we even need the crossover frequency anyway.  He uses it in a bunch of unexplained calculations to find the z parameter of the general expression for the transfer function of a PID, but it's really hard to follow his logic.  And in case the notation he's using isn't standard, this is what he gave as the expression for the tf of a PID:
[image]

Is there a way to just do this graphically, like they do in the linked article, by examining the effect of each parameter on the step response plot?  Or is there a different type of plot I should be looking at to see the effect of the parameters on bandwidth? I know a bode plot will let me see the phase margin.

I know I could just use MatLab's `pidtuner` function like they also show in the linked article, as that will let me specify the bandwidth and phase margin, and I probably will as check, but I'd like to get some understanding of how bandwidth and PM are affected by/related to the PID parameters instead of just using a function that feels like a black box.